# Build swagger-ui from open-api.yml

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm trying to generate interfaces from Open-API specification and I have a Gradle plugin:

```
implementation(
    "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.12",
    "org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:5.3.0"
)

def apiFile = "$rootDir/src/main/resources/openapi/api.yml"

task buildOpenApi(type: GenerateTask) {
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec = apiFile
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated"
    groupId = "$project.group"
    id = "$project.name-java-client"
    version = "$project.version"
    apiPackage = "com.example.my.api"
    modelPackage = "com.example.my.model"
    configOptions = [
            interfaceOnly: "true",
            openApiNullable: "false",
            skipDefaultInterface: "true"
    ]
    globalProperties = [
            apis: "",
            models: ""
    ]
    enablePostProcessFile = true
    skipOverwrite = false
}

compileJava.dependsOn(buildOpenApi)
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['build/generated/src','src/main/java']
```

And have an `api.yml` file that is located in `src/main/resources/openapi/api.yml`. When I run `./gradlew clean compileJava`, it generates me correct interfaces to the build directory, so I can implement them. But when I launch my application and go to `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html` I see swagger automatically generated from my controller classes, but not from `api.yml` file - I mean, it doesn't have any descriptions, examples and so on

How to make swagger built from my api.yml file, not from controller source code?

Comment: In *From controller source code* do you mean that you have other swagger annotations on controller class? If you use the Gradle plugin, you only have to implement generated interfaces. If in the controller class, which implements API interface, you have your own annotations, generated doc could be overridden.

Comment: No, I have removed all annotations from controller classes, but looks like it still generates from there, because there's no any description

Comment: Could you add your generated API interface and constructor class code to your question?

Comment: You'll have to serve Swagger UI [`dist` assets](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) manually and point `index.html` to your `api.yml` file. That said, the actual issue seems to be that the openapi-generator doesn't add some info from your OpenAPI definition to the generated controllers. I suggest you open an issue at https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is not to expect swagger from implemented interfaces, but build it from `api.yml` file. This config in `application.yml` helped me:

```
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: false
    path: /api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
    url: /api.yml
    path: /api-docs
```

Now swagger available at `localhost:8080/api-docs`